# Domain Driven Design Challenge - For which domain an entity belongs?

Tags: domain-driven-design, analysis

I'm analyzing a fairly enterprise resource planning software and because an ERP covers many areas from accounting to sales and CRM I have chosen to use Domain Driven Design. Now I have two questions :

1. What are main APPLIED (not in theory) resources to start DDD?
2. How can I find out for example to which Domain or Module an "Invoice"
   belongs ? Does it belongs to "Accounting" or "Sales"?

There may be many examples of such situation where I get confuse when separating  Entities and Domains...

How can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](http://www.amazon.com/Implementing-Domain-Driven-Design-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0321834577/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1361265364&sr=8-1&keywords=implementing+domain+driven+design) might be a good resource for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a DDD authority in any way, but here's my 2 cents

1) Have you read the blue bible? The examples there are taken from Eric Evans experience building a real shipping platform. I haven't seen any other published example as big as the one in the book.

2) *Invoice* can belong to both, but it will probably mean different things on each domain, in sales it will be linked to an order, payment and so on; in Accounting it will be linked to a Ledger and an Account.
You won't find a unique domain to solve the whole ERP problem. I'm not experienced with ERPs, but knowing sales and CRM, I would say that you might find 15+ different domains, some will be tiny frameworks, some will be solve chunky parts of the problem.

About your confusion: What I've done in the past is to find questions related to DDD here in SO (some are really enlightening) and read blogposts from people who know quite a lot about DDD  - [lostechies](http://lostechies.com) have quite a few good blogposts about DDD.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is two resources i would recommend that use DDD in practice: the first one is the one and only famous book [Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns_ With Examples in C# and .NET.pdf](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202), and the other one is [dotNET Domain Driven Design with C# - Problem - Design - Solution.pdf](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147563) but they both assume you have read Eric Evan's book first.
2. i don't think anyone is qualified to answer the second question very well, and most people will say it depends on context and you particular application. the hard truth is that DDD is about design and it requires sophisticated skills (it is not easy). so i will suggest you develop your code incrementally with backing tests so you could change you design when the right moment comes (that what eric refers to as a Breakthrough).